# Extracting user agent from logs

Tags: java, python, regex

I have large log files in which I am getting a field which contains the user-agent. Now the position of this field can vary from log to log and I am trying to extract the complete user-agent string as it is. 
So far the regex options that I have tried are not working for all the user-agents that I am getting in these logs. They seem to be working for most of them though.

The following are some sample user-agents that I am getting in the logs

> "field1" "field2" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_0) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.65 Safari/535.11"
>
> "field1" "Sundance(Compatible; Windows; U; en-US;) Version/0.9.0.38" "field2" "field3"
>
> "yacybot (i386 Linux 2.6.24-24-generic; java 1.6.0_07; Europe/en) http://yacy.net/bot.html" "field1" "field2"
>
> "field1" "field2" "Lynx/2.8.5rel.1 libwww-FM/2.14 SSL-MM/1.4.1 OpenSSL/0.9.7m"

The regex that I have using ( that is not working for all of them ) is as below

```
([^/\s]*)(/([^\s]*))?(\s*\[[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\])?\s*(\((([^()]|(\([^()]*\)))*)\))?\s*
```

The original logs are space separated fields (something similar to squid logs) wrapped in quotes so I can be sure of the start and the end of the user-agent string in each log line. But the position of the fields vary in each log file.

It would be best if I can get some help in improving this regex pattern. What I require is that the regex be able to match all of the above user-agent strings that I have listed.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

What I am trying to achieve is that I need to extract the field that contains the user-agent string from different log files. The logs files contain series of fields that are space separated and wrapped in quotes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I never asked you to be a regex-writing-service nor a provider of library recommendations. I said I have written a regex which needs more refinement. And no, none of the related questions helped thats why I posted my own.

Comment: *"if anyone can direct me to any third party library"*... Also, it would be helpful to offer more detail than *"not working for all of them"* (what were you expecting, and what did you get instead?)

Comment: I was expecting that the regex that I have shared would be able to catch all the user-agents. But there are some exceptional cases where this regex seems to fail. I have shared the exceptional cases in the post.

Comment: It's impossible without some constraints on other fields - in what ways they *don't* look like user agent string?

Comment: The other fields are either Strings(hardware name or service names) or IPs and they are all wrapped in qoutes as well.

Comment: All fields as strings : what is the difference between field1, field2 or field3 and a user agent string ? Is the user agent string the only that contains blanks ? That would be a true caracteristic.

Comment: Yes, only the user agent string contains blanks. The rest of the fields are just single word or phrase or ip addresses.

Comment: "only the user agent string contains blanks" This doesn't help much though, since it doesn't eliminate the possibility of a user agent that doesn't contain blanks. If all user agents contain blanks and no other field contains blanks, then it's as simple as finding all "[^\s]*"|"(.*)" matches and only keeping the ones with a captured group: https://www.debuggex.com/r/mEHs1VRgGrJETyKI

Comment: Sorry, the regex above should actually be "[^\s]*"|"([^"]*)" https://www.debuggex.com/r/I5C5Ll8rCVQcpGgw

Comment: could you give an example log-line where your regex workes and point out which is `field`, `user-agent` and how were you able to distinguish between the two

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key to answering this question lies in identifying commonality between all user agent strings which can't be present in any of the other fields. Problem is that's easier said than done, especially since there are only conventions for its format - not hard and fast rules. However lists of real user agent strings do exist, e.g. [here](http://www.user-agents.org/allagents.xml) and [here](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Browserlist/).

Examples below - choose your preferred option or mix and match:

1. Look for at least one space - user agent in quotes *(simplest but apparently wouldn't work for the first ever user agent string, which was [`"Mosaic/0.9"`](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/01/12/history-of-the-user-agent-string/))*:

   `"[^"]* [^"]*"`
2. Look for at least one version number (two digits separated by a decimal point - *only if guaranteed not to be in any of the other fields*) - user agent in first capturing group:

   `"([^"]*\d\.\d[^"]*)"`
3. Look for something more complicated (*may be your best bet if neither of the above work, you have a finite list of known user agents and the search text can't be in any of the other fields*) - unquoted user agent using lookahead:

   `[^"]*(mozilla|opera|ipad|applewebkit|khtml|7b405|bot|sundance|lynx|etc|etc)[^"]*(?=")`

   [image: Regular expression visualization]

   [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/qO80juZpD2P6UFgN)

Comment: No I am afraid the user-agent can come in any position. I explained in the post that the position of the fields may vary. +1 for the demo though

Comment: OK sorry - will look again. Would suggest updating your post to include examples where there are fields after the user agent.

Comment: No probs Saif. Not sure I understand the downvoting on this, personally thought it was an interesting question.

Comment: My thoughts exactly Steve. But am glad that I was able to explain you what I wanted and you helped me get there.